# Why are there two functions which do the exact same thing? Why must be invoked differently in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, kotlin-function-type

```
fun main() {
    fun evenFn(num: Int): Boolean {
        return num % 2 == 0
    }
    val evenFn = fun(num: Int) = num % 2 == 0
    val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    println(list.filter(evenFn))
    println(list.filter { evenFn(it) })
}
```

How is it that I can declare two `evenFns`  with the same name (one is stored in a variable and the other is just defined) and I have to invoke them in different ways? In JavaScript, doing so would throw an error saying that there is already an `evenFn`.

Can someone explain why the two `evenFns` are treated different by the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fun evenFn` is a method; `val evenFn` is a local variable which happens to have a function type. In Kotlin (and Java, and C#, etc. etc.) it's allowed to have a method and a local variable with the same name in scope, and the type of the local variable doesn't affect these rules.

Answer (score 0):

Doing so in Javascript wouldn't throw an error. In Javascript functions are hoisted to the top of the scope.

If you were to write code such as

```js
var test = function() { 
    console.log('a');
}

function test() {
    console.log('b');
}

test();
test.apply();
```

the second function definition would be hoisted to the top to create code that reads as

```
var test = function() { console.log('b'); }
var test = function() { console.log('a'); }
```

As you can see, the function definition is overwritten by the variable definition. The output would therefore be

```
a
a
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/rudepokuka/edit?js,console, actually throws an error, so you need to remove the var declaration in your first statement, becuase you want to reassign it not re-declare it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, after reading the Function types section of the kotlin documentation. You need a callable reference to local functions , member functions to pass them around as references.